# Wine not work in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, wine

There is bash in cron script with wine executing. In cronjob log I see:

```
wine: Unhandled exception 0x0eedfade in thread 9 at address 0xce99ebf0:0x7b83e6ce (thread 0009), starting debugger...
err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:seh:setup_exception_record stack overflow 928 bytes in thread 0009 eip 7bc843a0 esp 00230f90 stack 0x230000-0x231000-0x330000
```

I tryed two approaches to avoid this problem, but no one worked.

1) In bash script:

```
DISPLAY= wine my_program.exe
```

2) In crontab

```
52 15 * * * export DISPLAY= && bash myscript.sh >> /var/log/mylog.log 2>&1
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: provide a correct X-Server that is configured to accept connections via the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: How to do this for cron? I very confused because my_program.exe is console, not graphical.

Answer (score 2):

The binary `wine` is meant for graphical programs, it needs an X server to run. If your program doesn't have a graphical interface, use [`wineconsole`](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/cui-programs) instead.

```
wineconsole my_program.exe
```

Comment: Unfortunately not work with **wineconsole**

Comment: _err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Error opening terminal: unknown._

Comment: Strange, wineconsole should work without X. Well, then you are back to doing what the error told you in the first place: `Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY`

Comment: One thing you can still try: `wineconsole --backend=curses my_program.exe`. According to the documentation the curses backend is supposed to be the default, but it can't hurt to try to force it.

Comment: I tryed add option _--backend=curses_ but new error raised

Comment: _Error opening terminal: unknown._